# How can I trigger a Meteor template to update manually even if the dependencies didn't change?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, spacebars

The reason I'm asking is because I'm evaling a compiled different version of the template at runtime and want to re-execute it and update all instances of it already rendered to the dom.

I imagine something like Templates.some_name.changed() which I can call that would do that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem would be getting the template instance object outside that template's helper functions, which may be possible using private methods, but I'm not sure how off the top of my head.

However, you can just make a new dependency for this specific purpose.

```
some_nameDep = new Deps.Dependency();
```

In one of your `Templates.some_name.helpers` functions add (before the function returns):

```
some_nameDep.depend();
```

If it doesn't have any helpers, add one that includes that line but returns nothing and make sure you call the helper within the spacebars template itself.

Then you can re-execute all `some_name` instances with:

```
some_nameDep.changed();
```

Comment: Fantastic idea!!! I'm going to give that a try. That should definitely be good for now. I do bet there is a method though, a private one, we can call.